# data.table join is hard to understand

Tags: r, data.table

I am learning data.table in R.  This join confuses me for hours.  Can someone help me understand it?

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = rep(c("b", "a", "c"), each = 3),
                y = c(1, 3, 6),
                v = 1:9)
DT
#>   x y v
# 1: b 1 1
# 2: b 3 2
# 3: b 6 3
# 4: a 1 4
# 5: a 3 5
# 6: a 6 6
# 7: c 1 7
# 8: c 3 8
# 9: c 6 9
X = data.table(x = c("c", "b"),
               v = 8:7,
               foo = c(4, 2))
X
#>   x v foo
# 1: c 8   4
# 2: b 7   2
```

And this join result is beyond me.

```
DT[X, on = .(x, y <= foo)]
#>   x y v i.v
# 1: c 4 7   8
# 2: c 4 8   8
# 3: b 2 1   7
```

What is it doing?

Comment: i corrected what I believe to be a typo: `c(x, y <= foo)` --> `.(x, y <= foo)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a non-equi join :

- joins same x on both tables : `b` and `c` in this case
- keeps only the values of DT where `DT$y <= X$foo`

Perhaps easier to understand like this :

```
DT[X,.(x.x, x.y, x.v, i.x, i.v, i.foo,`y < foo`= x.y < i.foo ), on = .(x = x, y <= foo)]

   x.x x.y x.v i.x i.v i.foo y < foo
1:   c   1   7   c   8     4    TRUE
2:   c   3   8   c   8     4    TRUE
3:   b   1   1   b   7     2    TRUE
```

Where:

- `x.` are the columns of the `LHS` table (`DT`)
- `i.` are the columns of the `RHS` table (`X`), to remember `i.` think about `DT[i,j,by]`.

Comment: (yet another) Perhaps, use `.(x, x.y, ..` instead of `.(x, y, ...` (otherwise the values in column `y` of resulting table is actually values of `foo`.

Answer (score 6):

A join tries to match rows of the left (`DT`) & right (`X`) tables.

Which rows should be matched?

`on` tells us two conditions, always left-then-right

1. `x`, short-hand for `x == x`, i.e., `DT$x == X$x`
2. `y <= foo` means `DT$y <= X$foo`.

Note also that we are using the right table to "look up" rows of the left table. That means we go through the rows of `X` and see which rows of `DT` match.

Let's start with `X[1]`. What rows of `DT` match?

- `X[1]$x` is `c`. There are 3 corresponding rows of `DT` (7,8,9).
- `X[1]$foo` is `4`. There are 6 corresponding rows of `DT` (1,2,4,5,7,8)

There are 2 rows satisfying both conditions: 7, 8.

Now we move to `X[2]`. What rows of `DT` match?

- `X[2]$x` is `b`. There are 3 corresponding rows of `DT` (1,2,3).
- `X[2]$foo` is `2`. There are 3 corresponding rows of `DT` (1,4,7)

There is only one row satisfying both conditions: 7.

So the output has 3 rows, 2 matching `X[1]` and 1 matching `X[2]`.

That tells us about the rows -- now we need to think about what *columns* will be in the result.

The query doesn't specify any columns, so the default is to include *all* columns from both tables. `x` and `y` will come from `X` (with `y` coming from `X$foo`) by default since they are part of the join condition. There is a collision on `v` (it's present in both `DT` and `X`), so we get `v` from the left (i.e. `DT$v`) and `i.v` from the right (i.e. `x$v`).